# How to make cases in switch statement to be indented in Emacs

Tags: php, emacs, syntax, indentation

How to make Emacs to indent cases like this

```
switch ($foo) {
    case "foo":
        $foo .= " bar";
        break
    case "bar":
        $foo .= " baz";
        break
    default:
        $foo .= " undefined";
}
```

instead of

```
switch ($foo) {
case "foo":
    $foo .= " bar";
    break
case "bar":
    $foo .= " baz";
    break
default:
    $foo .= " undefined";
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add something like this to your .emacs (either as a general setting or for the specific programming modes you care about):

```lisp
;; set this in all c-based programming modes
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
             (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)))
```

to add this to another mode, use the same pattern above with the relevant mode name substituted in for the hook, e.g.: `<mode-name>-hook`.

Comment: `c-set-offset` is bound to `C-c C-o` if you need to adjust something on the fly for a specific file.

Comment: Thanks. I put 4 as offset and it work for php-mode and C-mode. Do you know how to set it for JavaScript too?

Comment: @jcubic - what javascript mode do you use?

Comment: @jcubic - so you could just use `js-mode-hook` per my added note above.

Comment: Yes I try it (also `javascript-mode-hook`) and it doesn't work for JS. I also try to set `statement-case-intro` with no results in JS

Comment: There is a slight typo in your elisp.  The c-set-offset call should look like: (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)  (the "+" should be quoted).